# Can we Run hive query using SSH and passing file from local

Tags: ssh, hive

I want to Run hive query from external cluster like below.

```
ssh user@<ipaddress> hive -f <localfilepath>
```

It works successfully if we have file on the cluster but wont work for local file.

Is there way to achieve  this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logical point of view, immediatly after the command "ssh user@" you are "inside" that host. So you can't see the files from external cluster.

You could do it in two steps:

1. push the file to cluser
2. execute it

Comment: Speaking of pushing file to cluster, you can consider the file transportation software such as FileZilla.